# String (with fraction) to Double in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have a column in my DataFrame which contains values like `99 230/256`. It's a String with a fraction. It's double representation is `99.8984375`.

How do I apply a transformation which converts such Strings to Double in Spark? I'm using Spark 1.6.2

Comment: You'll need to create an udf to parse it, compute the fraction value and return a double.

Comment: Yes. I agree. I was looking to see if this can be handled by any predefined methods, but you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: You have to define your own function to apply to the data. Spark just uses that, it isn't a built-in feature to do what you are asking.

Since you didn't specify which API you are using, here's a Python answer over a simple collection.

Also, you can run and test this completely outside of Spark.

```
def convertFrac(frac):
    parts = frac.split()
    whole = numer = 0
    denom = 1
    if len(parts) == 2:
        whole = float(parts[0]) 
        numer, denom = map(float, parts[1].split('/'))
    elif len(parts) == 1:
        if '/' in parts[0]:
            numer, denom = map(float, parts[0].split('/'))
        else:
            return float(parts[0])
    return whole + (numer / denom)
```

Here's a sample run

```
>>> sc.parallelize(["99 230/256", "1/100"]).map(convertFrac).collect()
[99.8984375, 0.01]
```

Warning, this doesn't work on all inputs (especially negatives like `"-2 3/5"` needs to be written as `"-2 -3/5"`) - it is only an example of what you need to do.

Comment: I am using Scala API but this definitely helps. There is also no scope of negative values so your function works perfect. Also, I chose to manipulate the column in `spark-sql`'s `select` clause (not sure if it's a good idea) but I found it much easier to do it in sql (personal preference, though!). Thank you for the code.

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, just simple value casting and string splitting. Nothing too complicated.